# Paho MQTT vs MQTT paho spring integration

Tags: java, spring, mqtt, paho

While I was fixing some issues in my client within an application using paho and spring framework, I discovered the spring MQTT integration. I'm not sure if this fix my problems, and I not even sure what is this.

Could someone explain what is the difference of using this together?

Do spring framework bring errors into paho that the integration solve?

or is save enough use this two technologies separate?

The dependencies used by me are:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and :

```
<dependency>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

The integration of the dependency below it will be quite painful. I want to know if there is any advantage on doing this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-mqtt</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Integration is sub framework in Spring eco system which allows to configure Enterprise Integration Patterns easily for Enterprise Application Integration.

It is good if you want to do processing of data with Source, Filter, Accumulator, Processor, Sink kind of a architecture with highly cohesive and loosely coupled components.

It is ideal to use where you have multiple systems speaking different protocols together which needs to integrated to with other systems without much fuss.